# UIImagePickerController write my own delegate (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates

i'm trying to implement my own delegate for the class UIImagePickerController

This is the method that call the camera

```
- (IBAction)acquisisciFoto:(id)sender{
    ImagePickerDelegate *pickerDelegate = [[ImagePickerDelegate alloc] init];
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setDelegate:pickerDelegate];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:NO];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; 
}
```

ImagePickerDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ImagePickerDelegate : NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end
```

ImagePickerDelegate.m

```
#import "ImagePickerDelegate.h"

@implementation ImagePickerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"test");
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}

@end
```

But nothing work and i have this error:

sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 9A334)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
(gdb)

PS. with delegate:self work good, but i need to use 2 btn in the same view and they have to fire the camera.

Please help me

Comment: When you say "nothing works", do you mean the camera view does not appear or only that the delegate methods do not get hit after a picture is successfully taken?

Comment: the camera view does not appear

Comment: or better, appears the shutter and the app crash

Comment: If you set a breakpoint where you create the UIImagePickerController in your acquisisciFoto action, can you actually hit the breakpoint? are you doing your testing on a device or in the simulator?

Comment: the program reach the breakpoint, I can not test it in the simulator because the debugger returns that there isn't a camera, on the device the app crash

Comment: What kind of object is self (where you are creating your `UIImagePickerController` from) and is it derived from UIViewController?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: The version of your SDK probably doesn't match the version of iOS on your iPhone.  There have been [many similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uuid+mismatch+detected%22&submit=search) on here.